# Disabling display of the full file path in Visual Studio 2008's 'Find Results' window

Tags: visual-studio-2008, find

In Visual Studio 2008, in the Find Results window, how do I not show the full path of the file name where the match was found?

The thing that I'm trying to get around is where most of the window is just displaying a long path rather than the chunk of text where the match was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do it within the Visual Studio 2008 UI (I even checked 2010 - nothing). However, there is a way to make changes to this using the registry. The link below should help. It is based on Visual Studio 2005, and it does work for Visual Studio 2008 as well. Just change the registry location.

From: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Find

To: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Find

Source: *[Customize your Find in Files Results experience!](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2006/03/30/565002.aspx)*.

Comment: I wonder how this could be accomplished also for the Find symbol results window

Comment: To sum up the link - Add a new string called `Find result format` (to the registry key mentioned) with a value of `$f$e($l,$c):$t\r\n` - where $f is the filename, $e is the extension, $l is the line, $c is the column, $t is the text on the line